# react-i18Next: Using an enum for translation key values

Tags: reactjs, enums, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

We are using i18Next in our React project and I wonder if there is way to use an enum for keys of the translation file to avoid typos while using it like this:

```
export enum AppLocaleKey {
  test = 'test'
}

...

import translationEN from './locales/en/translation';
const resources = {
  en: { translation: translationEN },
  ...
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    ...
  })

...

const translation = {
  [AppLocaleKey.test]: 'Test...',
};

export default translation;

...

import { AppLocaleKey } from './locales/localeKeys';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const App = (props: Props) => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <>
      <p>{t(AppLocaleKey.test)}</p>
    <>
  )
}
```

But this didn't work. Do you know any similar method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using TS you can with ts4.1 declare all the keys of the json as a valid inputs.

Check out the [official example](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react-typescript4.1),

And [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react-typescript4.1/namespaces?file=/src/App.tsx) out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
export enum VisitorType {
    SCHOOL_VS,
    SCHOOL_NOT_VS,
    GROUP,
    PRIVATE
}
```

...

```
resources: {
            en: {
                translation: {
                    visitorType: {
                        [VisitorType.SCHOOL_VS]: 'State school',
                        [VisitorType.SCHOOL_NOT_VS]: 'Non state school',
                        [VisitorType.GROUP]: 'Private groups',
                        [VisitorType.PRIVATE]: 'Private'

                    },
                }
            },
```

...

```
t(`visitorType.${VisitorType.SCHOOL_VS}`)
```